# Implementing an Event Handler C#

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

A `c#` application is writting on a `MS SQL` DB table at several times.
the records of this table must  be read and procceessed by another `c#` application.

At the moment I have implemented I Threading timer which looks (every 2 secs) if the table has rows and proccess the data:

```
System.Threading.Timer checkTimer;

checkTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, 2000, 500);

private void InitSQLCon()
{
    Con = new SqlConnection(ConectionString);
    Con.Open();
}        

private void Callback(Object state)
{
    string queryString = "Select [Wi_Customer ID],[Wi_License_plate_ID] from " + Properties.Settings.Default.Table1 + " where Wi_Car_Rfid='" + s + "'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Con);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
      ///...make neccessary operations
    }       
}
```

My problem is that the current implementation isn't effecient. 
Checking the table with a timer is resource consuming.
I would like to do it in an event driven way.
Ideally I would like to implement and event handler raised by the `add record to table1`
event.
If this possible (since I have never implemented an event handler) I would appreciate any feedbacks on how this can be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anything in C# that can be used as database Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807513/is-there-anything-in-c-sharp-that-can-be-used-as-database-trigger)

Comment: Also - why are you creating new SqlConnection every time instead of closing and reopening it again?

Comment: Who's inserting the record? Your application or another 3rd party?

Comment: @Tarec well in this case IMO it's not bad, process is long time running and it's used few milliseconds every two seconds...

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit He wrote that he has 2 applications - 1 that writes to DB and 1 that reads from it, which code is presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* some change tracking features in SQL Server, most notable exposed via `SqlDependency` - however, frankly I think you'd do better to look at a **separate** notification mechanism. For example, I'm a big fan of redis pub/sub, because it is *ridiculously* simple to set up (heck, a dedicated pub-sub server doesn't even need persistence, so the "bgsave"/"fork" issue that makes redis tricky on windows doesn't apply, so you could just use the redis-server available on nuget). Then you just have your worker subscribe to a named channel, and you have the other parts of the system broadcast a message to that named channel when they add work. Simple and efficient. For robustness, you'd also want to *periodically* poll manually - but probably on a much slower poll - maybe every 30 seconds or something.

---

Here's an example of pub/sub using redis via [BookSleeve](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BookSleeve) (you will also need a [redis-server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Redis-64/) running on the local machine):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using BookSleeve;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // IMPORTANT: the "pub" and "sub" can be on entirely separate machines,
        // as long as they are talking to the same server. They are only shown
        // together here for convenience
        using (var sub = new RedisSubscriberConnection("localhost"))
        using (var pub = new RedisConnection("localhost"))
        {
            sub.Open();
            pub.Open();

            sub.Subscribe("busytime", (queue,payload) =>
            {
                // you don't actually need the payload, probably 
                var received = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload);
                Console.WriteLine("Work to do! Look busy!: " + received);
            });

            string line;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter messages to send, or q to quit");
            while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && line != "q")
            {
                pub.Publish("busytime", line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```