# "Universal" SQLDependency and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, sqldependency

I need to notify to my entity framework when an update is made in my database.

I have read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/496484/SqlDependency-with-Entity-Framework). It is very useful, but only for sql server.

Does it exists something similar, based on Entity Framework, but available for all DBMS?

If not, how can I reach my goal (notify update from every type of dbms) without a dumb polling?

Comment: Available for all DBMS? AFAIK no...but it can be done not too much obtrusive (with triggers and a small _log table_ as sketched [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17807896/1207195))